# guid in file uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I use these following codes for using guid for file names in asp.net uploading forms.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)
    {
        Guid filename = new Guid();
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + filename.ToString());
    }
}
```

But it only shows one file name and it's 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

how can I solve this problem.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change you code to this:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)
{
    string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // you used one extra new before Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. i have edit your code by the way.

Comment: thanks. no visual studio installation on my laptop :)

Answer (score 1):

Guid use factory pattern approach
change

```
Guid filename = new Guid();
```

to

```
string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: thanks. that's right. but there is a problem with you code you should use Guid filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); you must use string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();